# Reordering columns in the ASP.NET GridView after it is rendered

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with large number of columns and my customer wants to compare the data between two columns(basically by dragging and dropping the columns so that interested columns are next to each other). As far as I know ASP.NET GridView by default do not support. I use .NET 4.0. Is this supported by ASP.NET GridView ? Is there any other open source control which can help me ?